# Extracting data from a certain position on each line of a text file

Tags: python, loops, text-files

I'm working with the following text file I imported as follows:

```
url = 'https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/datasets/2016/2016-state-and-county/est16all.txt'
url_get.urlretrieve(url, 'poverty.txt')
```

I want to extract parts of the text file for each line starting at position 49, the maximum # of characters being 8.  So I try the following:

```
with open('poverty.txt', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        data.seek(49)
        print(data.readline(8))
```

The output, however, just repeats the values from the first line of the `txt` file for the number of lines in the file.  This is obviously incorrect.

```
14115713
14115713
14115713
14115713
14115713
14115713
14115713
14115713
```

How do I construct my loop such as to extract the values from *each* line at the 50th position?

Answer (score 3):

The `readlines()` method splits data into a tuple with each line as an item in the tuple.

```py
with open('some_file.txt','r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        f,l = 1, 64 # the slice you want to take
        print(line[f:l])
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `readlines` method on the open file object, then slice the line string:

```
with open('poverty.txt', 'r') as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        print(line[49:57])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for 9th element of this data, then you can use

```
 with open('est16all.txt') as fd:
   for line in fd:
     print (line.split()[8])
```

or lets say if you want to use slices from 49 to 49+8 then

```
 with open('est16all.txt') as fd:
   for line in fd:
     print (line[49:49+8].lstrip())
```

Output sample:

```
[root@bazooka2 ha_vxt]# python find_missing.py | more
14115713
267674
2588
7881
2146
1263
2568
995
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your *problem* correctly, you can try something like this:

```
In [01]: with open('something.txt', 'r') as data:
    ...:     for line in data:
    ...:         print(line[48:57])
```

You are using `line` to iterate through `data` but then you're seeking data to 49 at every loop and read the same 8 chars over and over again for for how many lines the file has.